# Account name should append in contact

Tags: apex

I want to write a trigger on contact such that whenever I create a contact it must include the related Account name also like if Account name is Anzar and I create a contact named Mohammad, then the contact name should come like this "Mohammad Anzar".

```
trigger trig on Contact (before insert,before update)
{
    for(contact con : trigger.new)
    {
        con.lastname += ' '+ con.account.name;
    }
}
```

by this the contact is created but null is coming with the contact name.

Comment: You are getting null because you can't get relationship object values inside account so you need to query that data first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it this way

```
trigger trig on Contact (before insert,before update)
{
    Set<Id> acctIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(contact con : trigger.new) {
      acctIds.add(con.AccountId);
    }
    Map<Id,Account> mapAccts = new Map<Id, Account>([select Id, Name from Account where id in :acctIds]);

    for(contact con : trigger.new)
    {
        con.lastname += ' '+ mapAccts.get(con.accountId).name;
    }
}
```

Comment: since I am a beginner cant we simplify this.

Comment: I don't think you can simplify it much more. Just copy-paste that code in your trigger and you're set. Besides, this could be a good learning experience. What is it that "scares" you about that code?

Comment: Map :( I dont know much about it...but thanks i should just learn about it first.

Comment: "Map" is a list of Key-Value pairs... super simple and awesome. You can read about it here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm. But don't let it scare you! Paste the code, see it work, and explore! That's what makes a good developer!

Comment: If it does, please upvote and mark as accepted so others can benefit. :)

Answer (score -1):

1: This not bulkiy but it will work

```
for(Contact con: Trigger.New)
   {
      Account acc=[Select id,Name from Account where id=:con.AccountId];
      con.FirstName=''+acc.Name;     

   }
```

2:

```
List<Account> lstacc=new  List<Account>([Select id,Name from Account]);
   for(contact con : trigger.new)
    {
      for(Account acc:lstacc)
      {
          if(con.AccountId==acc.id)
          {
           con.FirstName=''+ acc.Name;
          }
      }        
    }
```

Comment: Your first solution is not bulk friendly and the second breaks if the org has more than 10000 accounts. What is the point to add an answer to a question with an accepted (and correct) one if you can't improve on it?